# Flex: How to find out if an object is in a page using SSL/TLS [https protocol]

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, ssl, https

what's the best and shortest way to get this information?

i've read about BrowserInvokeEvent which contains a boolean of the sort - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/BrowserInvokeEvent.html#isHTTPS,

yet i havn't been able to implement it.

If it's possible, i'd appreciate an example.

Comment: Hi @wvxvw

I'm trying to make a browser plugin. I've realized it's an Air component and was asking of it's possible Flex equivalent.

Flextras got what i wanted to achieve.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this as Flex/Flash/ActionScript I assume you want to know if your SWF file is served from n a page using SSL/TLS.  There is no 100% way to find this information.

If you want to know what the [URL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#url) of the SWF is, you can use the URL property of the Application tag.  Then run it through [URLUtils.isHttpsURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html#isHttpsURL%28%29) to find whether the URL is an HTTPS URL.

If you want to know the URL of the enclosing page, you can get at that using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and JavaScript code.  However, if the SWF and the enclosing page are not on the same domain this can cause cross domain runtime errors.